# Autofill not working iphone angular

Tags: ios, angular

I have an application with Angular front, and i have a problem on my login web page. 
When I use the autofill on iphone to auto fill login and password input in my login page (ios 11.3), the login and the password are visible but when i click in my submit button, the application not detected value in input login and input password...
If I add any caracter in the login or the password input and I click on the submit button, it's working ...

Why the application doesn't detected autofill value ? It's an angular problems ?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Tested with Angular 7.1 and iOS 12.1